# Mysql in java usage, while(result.next()) with if and else

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem about if else usage in java with mysql.

My code is :

```
if (!result29.next() ) 
{
    System.out.println("No data");
} 
else {
    do {
        if(name1.equals(result29.getString("name2")))
        {
            //screen one  
            namedelete as = new namedelete();
            as.setVisible(true);
        }
        else
        {
            //screen two
            nameadd aek = new nameadd();
            aek.setVisible(true);
        }  
     } while (result29.next());
}
```

If I try to shortly tell this code, if **name2** (a mysql colum result) equal to **name1** (an entry value) opening the screen one, if not equal it is opening the screen two.

**Problem**

The problem is, if they are equal, **screen one** and **screen two** both opening. But, if not equal it is working normal, just screen two opening.

Can you help me, how can I fix that problem ?

Comment: You are running a while loop. you may get both the if and else statement executed for all set of records. why don't you break out of loop when if condition fulfills? jut put break in if and else and you won't be getting both the results.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is your result set contains multiple rows, some that equal, some that don't.

I think if you debugged your program, you would find that screen two is displayed many times.

Comment: Show us the SQL you are using. For your logic to work, your rowset must have at most 1 row. I can help with the query if you edit your question to include the query. Let md know Shen you've done that.